# Upgrading to Android Gradle Plugin 1.3 fails build due to check failure in Espresso tests

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, upgrade, android-lint

Before upgrading to Android Gradle Plugin 1.3, the custom lint scope was only Android source files.

After I upgraded to 1.3.1, my tests files started getting checked and as a scenario fails my custom lint rule, the build fails.

There is no documentation about this. I read some warnings have become fatal but nothing around test files getting scanned.

Anyone facing such an issue?

EDIT:

top level build.gradle

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath 'org.sonarqube.gradle:gradle-sonarqube-plugin:1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs './prebuilt-libs'
       }  
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}
```

Error:

HardCoding: Detects HardCoded "abc" string
../../src/androidTest/java/com/xyz/mobile/trips/test.java:108: HardCoding Found. *(This is my custom lint rule)*

hasExtra(CODE, **"abc"**)

Comment: Post your build.gradle and your error

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti.. added it as suggested by you.